# PHP Upload file to Apache server fails

Tags: php, apache

I have a form that submits a picture, screenshot is the name of the input tag.

In the php script I can print out $_FILES['screenshot']['name'], but when I try to get the temp folder it is saved in on the server with $_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], I get nothing.

Anyone know why? Seems like the file gets to the temp folder, but I can't get the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're stored in /tmp and removed on script completion as far as I remember..

You need to use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move the file to an accessible folder..

I.E.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], '/uploads/' . $_FILES['screenshot']['name']);
```